# pgfplots: Fill between makes xshift/yshift options for axis environment misbehave

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm using the `fillbetween` library of pgfplots and I want to shift the position of the `axis` environment with `xshift` and `yshift` options. However, there seems to be a discrepency between what the `tikzpicture` thinks where the axis is, and where the axis is really drawn. This only happens when there is at least one `fill between` command.

MWE (inspired by @marmot in [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444495/)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm]
            \addplot[name path=A,domain=0:1] {0};
            \addplot[name path=B,domain=0:1] {x};
            \addplot fill between [of=A and B]; % without this line, problem disappears
        \end{axis}
        \draw[thick,blue] (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

If I use the `standalone` document class, or use the `external` library of TikZ, or insert the figure in some text, the upper right part of the figure is cropped away:

[image: cropped]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't know what causes this behavior, a simple solution to the problem you're having is to use the `at={<coordinate>}` key.

Note the bounding box in the following examples (the red rectangle):

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    Using \verb|xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm|:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm]
            \addplot[name path=A,domain=0:1] {0};
            \addplot[name path=B,domain=0:1] {x};
            \addplot fill between [of=A and B]; % without this line, problem disappears
        \end{axis}

        \draw[thick,blue] (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
        \draw[thick,red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \vspace{1cm}
    Using \verb|at={(1cm,1cm)}|:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[at={(1cm,1cm)}]
            \addplot[name path=A,domain=0:1] {0};
            \addplot[name path=B,domain=0:1] {x};
            \addplot fill between [of=A and B]; % without this line, problem disappears
        \end{axis}

        \draw[thick,blue] (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
        \draw[thick,red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an already known bug in PGFPlots ([#199 in the PGFPlots tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/199/)). You can circumvent this problem by adding `set layers` and `cell picture=true` to the `axis` options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xshift=1cm,
            yshift=1cm,
            % add the following two lines to make it work
            % (for details see comments in bug #199
            %  <https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/199/>)
            set layers,
            cell picture=true,
        ]
            \addplot[name path=A,domain=0:1] {0};
            \addplot[name path=B,domain=0:1] {x};
            \addplot fill between [of=A and B]; % without this line, problem disappears
        \end{axis}
        \draw[thick,blue] (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]